# While connecting Teradata DB,It is taking saved password from local Data sources.

Tags: connection-string, teradata

While connecting Teradata DB,It is taking saved password from local Data sources(User DSN) in Control panel.

Connection string used :    "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=" & pwd & ";Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=False;User ID=" & user & ";Data Source=DCMQA;DSN=DCMQA"

If i give wrong password in UI also,it is taking the saved passed for user data sources(DCMQA) created in ODBC Data sources in control panel.

How to change the connection string to take the user,name password given in UI?

Can anyone plz help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been a fan of storing passwords with my DSN but I suppose there may be a valid reason to do so.

Can you create a system level ODBC DSN without a password and use that instead for referencing in your code?